# Disable single-right click , select row only by double-click on datagridview(winform)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to disable single-right click on datagridview,

and select row only by double-click

Datadridview property:

1.Fullrowselect

2.no multiselect

```
My Code:
     private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dgvindex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
    }


    private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index != dgvindex)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[dgvindex].Selected = true;
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dgvindex].Cells[0];

        }
    }
```

But it stuck when I double click the row

I want to set current row when double click and right click

and open a ContexMenuStrip when right click

Please give me some advices

What should i do?

Comment: one quick and dirty way is to derive from datagridview and override the WndProc() and check for the click and if it is simply return else just let it roll,but it will disable the single-click completly in your datagridview...

Comment: You are making this unnecessarily complicated.  When you do this, you no longer allow the user to edit a cell.  So just set ReadOnly = true and SelectionMode = FullRowSelect.  Done.

Comment: it's very unclear on what you actually want. I guess you may want to show the ContextMenu **only** if the right mouse is clicked on the current selected row, and to select a row user can simply click it or double click it, you should confirm or rephrase your problem.